# How to make the flutter app on android that constantly run in the background until force stop or uninstall it?

Tags: android, flutter

I want to create an app to send the user's position via the API.
My requirements are:

1. The app must auto-start in the background when after the mobile is powered on.
2. Swiping the app doesn't stop the app from working.

Only the user pressing `Force stop` or `Uninstall` to stop this app from working.
[image]

Comment: I don't think that Google will allow you to do that if you wish to publish your app on the Play Store.

Comment: And you would need Root privileges I would think. It is possible to listen for the `BOOT_COMPLETED` event and also to allow `auto_start` but not possible to do that without use of third party apps, to my understanding.

Comment: Hi @Arijeet, thank you for your info. I asked my work supervisor and the app must stay in the play store. So, fine remove this option.

Comment: Hi @Milie, thank you. I see another question about the auto-start app in a flutter. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

checkout this package it will help you to run your code in the background

```
workmanager: ^0.5.1
```